# How to open Edge in inprivate mode using selenium?

Tags: selenium-edgedriver

I am using the following code(C#) but its not working:

```
EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("about:InPrivate");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(myurl);
```

This is opening normal window instead of inprivate window. 
How to open this using selenium?